# Set flag for SIGFPE and continue execution ignoring FPEs

Tags: c, linux, floating-point, signals

In a numerical application, I'd like to know if a floating point exception occured after the computation finishes. By default, floating point divisions and invalid operations are ignored silently.

My attempt is to enable FPEs I care about, handle SIGFPE by setting a flag and disabling them again to allow execution to continue:

```
#include <fenv.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int caught = 0;
struct sigaction old_sa;
/* (2) */ fenv_t fenv_hold;

void sighandler()
{
    caught = 1;
    printf("Caught in handler, disabling\n");
    /* (1) */ fedisableexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    /* (2) */ feholdexcept(&fenv_hold);
    sigaction(SIGFPE, &old_sa, NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    volatile double a=1, b=0;

    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO; 
    sa.sa_sigaction = sighandler;
    sigaction(SIGFPE, &sa, &old_sa);

    feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO);
    printf("Dividing by zero..\n");
    a/=b;
    printf("Continuing\n");
}
```

I took two approaches, the first one labeled with `(1)`, the second one with `(2)`. Neither of them works as expected.

Output:

```
Dividing by zero..
Caught in handler, disabling
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

Expected Output:

```
Dividing by zero..
Caught in handler, disabling
Continuing
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with Floating Point exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219244/dealing-with-floating-point-exceptions)

Comment: 1) `void sighandler()` should be `void sighandler(int signum)` 2) you should not call printf from within a signal handler.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I know. This code is just for demonstration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to know, after a computation finishes, whether a floating-point exception occurred, then you should not use signals, as they have a high overhead. Instead, use the floating-point exception flags, which are set quickly by the processor during normal execution. (However, accessing them may have some performance effect.)

See the C standard on `<fenv.h>`. Briefly:

- Insert `#include <fenv.h>` in your source file.
- Insert `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on` before any source code that might access the floating-point flags or run under non-default floating-point modes.
- If desired, insert `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS off` after the above source code, when the following source code does not access the flags or run under non-default modes.
- Before a computation, execute `feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT)` to clear flags.
- After a computation, execute `fetestexcept(exceptions)` to test flags. `exceptions` should be a bitwise OR of `FE_DIVBYZERO`, `FE_INEXACT`, `FE_INVALID`, `FE_OVERFLOW`, and/or `FE_UNDERFLOW`, and possibly additional implementation-defined flags.

Note that some C implementations have poor support for accessing the floating-point environment.

Comment: If the implementation has poor support, using a signal handler won't work any better. The issue with support is that the compiler might make invalid optimizations that cause different exceptions to take place than should have happened on the abstract machine.